# Adding number to text rows sql server

Tags: sql-server, numbers

I have a columns named `id` and `item` and there are stored values like:

```
id item
1  value
2  value
3  value
```

etc. There are 192 rows. These values are in the system in different places and I need to find concrete value in database to change it to the name I need.

Is there some posibility to add number to rows, for example `value_01`, `value_02` etc.

I know how to do it in C language, but have no idea how to do it in sql server.

Edited:
@lad2025

In system I have `columns`, that names are stored in database. 
Names are same, for example:

In app `Apple` I have `table name Apple`

In app `Storage` I also have `table name Apple`

I need to change app `Storage` columns name `Apple` to different, but I dont know, which of databasa Apple values it is, so I want to add `identifiers` to string, to find the right one. So I need to update database values, to see them in system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b836b/3/0)**

```
DECLARE @pad INT = 3;

SELECT
[id],
[item] = [item] + '_' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @pad) + CAST([id] AS NVARCHAR(10)), @pad)
FROM your_table;
```

This will produce result like:

```
value_001
value_010
value_192
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your comments it is not clear what you want to achieve, but check:

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8c63/1/0)**

```
DECLARE @pad INT = 3;

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *,
    [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item)
  FROM your_table

)
SELECT
[id],
[item] = [item] + '_' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @pad) + CAST([rn] AS NVARCHAR(10)), @pad)
FROM cte
WHERE item = 'value';  /* You can comment it if needed */
```

Comment: Why use `REPLICATE` instead of '000'?

Comment: And if there is some other value name too, than I just need to add
where value name = 'value'??

Comment: Because when I want more 0 I just change '3' to '5' like `DECLARE @pad INT = 5; ... [item] = [item] + '_' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @pad) + CAST([id] AS NVARCHAR(10)), @pad)`

Comment: You should've included that in your answer.

Comment: @elly Yes if there is for example `product` you can filter it out using `WHERE item = 'value'`

Comment: But in this case I will change values only in database, but I will not update them in system

Comment: @elly provide sample data, it is not clear what you want, possibly I need to generate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item)` and add it instead of original Id

Comment: @lad025
Updated question.